# Making Ubuntu Bootable ISO: Truncating long file names

Tags: linux, installation, filesystems, iso-image, filenames

I am building a Custom Ubuntu ISO. Everything is ready in `custom-iso` folder. Therefore I apply this script to build my ISO.

```
#!/bin/bash
isoname=$(date +"custom-ubuntu-%y-%m-%d-%H:%M.iso")
mkisofs -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -z -iso-level 4 -c isolinux/isolinux.cat -o ./$isoname custom-iso/
```

However, in this method I am losing long file names and this causes installation to fail. For example:

```
What installer looks: fs-secondary-modules-3.2.0-23-generic-pae-di_3.2.0-23.36_i386.udeb
What it finds: fs-secondary-modules-3.2.0-23-generic-pae-di_3.2.0-23.36_i386.ud
```

How can I allow the mkisofs to have longer filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `-J` you acttivate the short Joliet format (max 64 characters). An alternative is the long version: `-joliet-long`

Or you can try using the rock-ridge extension using the parameter `-R` or `-rock`.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
mkisofs -RJ -joliet-long -o file.iso   <dirpath>
```

Combining all the options for Rock-Ridge extension and joliet long, retains the filenames